# Crash in debug build for mixed mfc dialog and mdi project

Tags: c++, tabs, mfc, mdi

I am working on a project which is a mixture of dialog and MDI. The project started as a tabbed dialog project. Later MDI was added to it. On clicking one of the tabs the MDI is invoked. Without clicking the a particular tab it remains only a dialog based project.
The project works fine in release build. When I do a debug build I get a crash when I click on the tab that initializes the MDI main frame and window. Given below is the piece of code that is executed for MID window creation.
The crash message is 
Unhandled exception at 0x590C0983 (msvcr120d.dll) in MarkBullV3.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Feel free to ask any question you may have.

Thanks & Regards,
Rakesh

```
            pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_Test1TYPE,
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CTest1Doc),
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), //custom MDI child frame
            RUNTIME_CLASS(CTest1View));
        if (!pDocTemplate)
            return FALSE;
        AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);



        pMainFrame = new CMainFrame;
        if (!pMainFrame || !pMainFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME1))
        {

            delete pMainFrame;
            return FALSE;
        }

        m_pMainWnd = pMainFrame;

            for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            theApp.OnFileNew();


        CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
        ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);
        pMainFrame->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);

        pMainFrame->UpdateWindow();

        totCustomPlotCount = 0;
```

//////////////////////Stack Below///////////////////////////////////////

```
msvcr120d.dll!_CrtDbgBreak() Line 87    C
msvcr120d.dll!_VCrtDbgReportA(int nRptType, void * returnAddress, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, char * arglist) Line 290    C
msvcr120d.dll!_CrtDbgReportV(int nRptType, void * returnAddress, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, char * arglist) Line 262 C
msvcr120d.dll!_CrtDbgReport(int nRptType, const char * szFile, int nLine, const char * szModule, const char * szFormat, ...) Line 279   C
mfc120d.dll!AfxAssertFailedLine(const char * lpszFileName, int nLine) Line 24   C++
mfc120d.dll!CScrollView::OnPrepareDC(CDC * pDC, CPrintInfo * pInfo) Line 387    C++
mfc120d.dll!CView::OnPaint() Line 185   C++
mfc120d.dll!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message, unsigned int wParam, long lParam, long * pResult) Line 2448    C++
mfc120d.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 2094  C++
mfc120d.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd, HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 282    C++
mfc120d.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 435 C++
mfc120d.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 299 C++
user32.dll!744084f3()   Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for user32.dll]    
[External Code] 
V3.exe!V10App::InitInstance() Line 291  C++
[External Code] 
V3.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 26    C++
[External Code]
```

/////////////////End of Stack /////////////////////////////////////

Comment: If you have a debug build, then just run in a debugger and let the debugger catch the crash in action, so you know where it actually happens. The debugger will also let you examine values of variables, and let you walk up the call stack so you can go to your code if the crash is in a system or library function.

Comment: Yeah I have a question.  When you had the crash, did you open your debugger and look at the call stack underneath the call into the C runtime library?  Could you edit the code in your question so that it doesn't have multi-level `&`-code translation?  Even one of your quotes has gone from `"` to `&quot;` to `&amp;quot;`.  So I've decided you really mustn't be that serious about getting an answer.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg  I have run in debugger tried to examine the variables. I am not getting enough clarity though. I can see most variables are fine and dont point to NULL. let me know if I can share the stack contents here. Is there a way I can send attachments.

Comment: Under your question, just below the tags, there is a line with a few links. One of them says "edit". Please edit your question to include all relevant information, including pointing out in the posted code where the crash happens, and also include the values of all involved variables.

Comment: Also edit the code to remove those html entities, those are not needed in formatted code.

Comment: @Joachim - I have edited  the html and also added the stack contents. Thanks

Comment: @paddy - I am very serious about getting and answer. This is my first time on stackoverflow and faced editing issues. Let me know what ever you think may be required I will be able to provide. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can easily see you get an ASSERT at line 387 in the function `CScrollView::OnPrepareDC`. Located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\viewscrl.cpp

And as you can read in the debug output and in the source code is the reason for this:

**Error: must call SetScrollSizes() or SetScaleToFitSize() before painting scroll view.**

Comment: I am not clear where to call SetScrollSizes or SetScaleToFitSize() since I am not handing scroll view myself in any way. The only thing I see is that class CTest1View : public CScrollView. Can you throw more light as where I should call the above functions. Its a bit surprising since this works fine in release mode.

Comment: No it doesn't work in Release mode. It also fails, but it throws no error.  That is a great difference. You defined to use a CScrollView in your project. If so you have to take care to init the view. And this isn't done. Just again read the the error message and read docs for CScrollView. Usually SetScrollSizes is called in OnInitialUpdate, or whenever OnSize is called. If you don't want a CScrollView don't use it ;)

Comment: Thanls xMRI. You are too very good. I could solve the problem by setting scrollsizes in updateinit. Though later I removed it because I didnt really need it. You were very fast in finding the problem. Thanks